# Stuck transactions

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, sending

I tried to send some bitcoins 2 days ago and they have sat there 0 confirmations - I guess because of 'dust' from faucets included in there.

I think I specified default transaction fee but obviously this wasn't enough.

How long will it take for transaction to be removed and balance to return to my wallet? or is there a way I can force it to cancel?

Any ideas how I can work out how much transaction fee to use to let this through?

The Transaction ID is 78e50449f91454fb33dfc0986b4e2efa909a4b19ba47569f22de11fad98eccad-000

Any help appreciated!

LCS

Comment: Blockchain.info has this message when I search that TXID: `Transaction rejected by our node. Reason: The Maximum number of inputs in a single transaction is 250`. That's not a network defined limit, probably just to prevent them from handling too much spam.

Comment: related: [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9046/5406)

Answer (score 2):

To check the recommended transaction fees for a specific time period you are willing to wait. You can refer to [BlockCypher](https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/). It will tell you the recommended fee to pay on a per kB basis for high priority process and etc..

So lets say, you really want to accelerate the whole process, what you could do is perform a Child pays for Parent transaction using the unconfirmed output of the transaction that is currently stuck and basically compensate for the fees you're missing out on the "stuck" transaction.

You can do this by creating a raw transaction using Bitcoin Core or some wallet software, then broadcast this to a well-connected peer and theoretically it would then eventually be committed to the Blockchain by Miners.

As it is right now, my full node mempool has approximately 4000+ Transactions, so it will be unlikely for your transaction to ever get committed to the Blockchain and eventually your stuck transaction will be removed from Mempools within the network.